# Reference/list of reductive subgroups of reductive groups?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a (say, connected) reductive group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (say, $\mathbb C$).

I am looking for simple examples of (ideally) complete characterizations of all reductive subgroups of a given $G$. For example say, of $G= GL(n)$ for small $n$.

EDIT:  For example, Nguyen, K. A., Marius van der Put, and Jakob Top. "Algebraic subgroups of GL2(C)." Indagationes Mathematicae 19, no. 2 (2008): 287-297. Gives a classification for GL(2,C), PGL(2,C), and SL(2,C)

Comment: For subgroups of maximal rank, there is an algorithm due to Borel and de Siebenthal, Comment. Math. Helv. 23 (1949), 200–221.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Borel-de Siebenthal theory only classifies subgroups $H \subset G$ where the rank of $H$ is equal to the rank of $G$. That's a very restrictive notion of "maximal rank" and it will not see the majority of maximal reductive subgroups.

Comment: ". . . for small $n$."  How small is small?  You are asking about faithful representations of reductive groups.

Comment: @JasonStarr whatever is known, I suppose? Asking for faithful representations puts the question the other way, more or less: I want to fix the target rather than the source

Comment: Dynkin, E. B. Maximal subgroups of the classical groups. (Russian) Trudy Moskov. Mat. Obšč. 1, (1952). 39–166.  English Transl.: Am Math. Soc., Transl., II, Ser 6, 245-378 (1957).

Comment: See also Chapter 6 of the book:  V. V. Gorbatsevich, A. L. Onishchik,  E. B. Vinberg,
 Structure of Lie groups and Lie algebras, Lie Groups and Lie Algebras III,
Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences, Vol. 41, Springer-Verlag,  Berlin, 1994.

Comment: For $n=1$, every $H$ is a torus.  For $n=2$, every $H$ is a torus, all of $\textbf{GL}_2$ or $\textbf{SL}_2$.

Comment: @JasonStarr thanks! forgive my ignorance, but i've also been trying to place $PGL_n$, for example, which has a faithful adjoint representation...

Comment: The smallest faithful linear representation of $\textbf{PGL}(V)$ is on $\text{Hom}(V,V)/\text{Id}_V$.